# Use PHP to split string into a date, and two integers

Tags: php, html, string

I have a string formatted like so '2014-07-11-4-8'. The '2014-07-11' part is the date, the '4' is an integer, and '8' is an integer. How can I split the original string into these 3 variables using PHP?

Comment: little hint for you:

use power of regexps, Luke!

Comment: @coramba : It's a valid way, but it's not necessary to use regexps for this. explode() is enough.

Comment: @Theox agree. actually there are dozen ways to do it. I just wanna see the guy tried something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a regular expression:

```
$string = '2014-07-11-4-8';

preg_match("/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})-(\d+)-(\d+)/", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);

$date = $matches[1];
$int1 = $matches[2];
$int2 = $matches[3];
```

Comment: This works! However, I have now added three letters onto the end to store a person's initials. How can I extract that as well? (The initials are also separated by a '-')

Answer (score -1):

```
$date  = "2014-07-11-4-8";
$array = explode("-", $date);
```

Then u can access each element in array variable